# Running decompiled file

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, decompiling

I was working on an Android app but yesterday my Hard disk got crashed and all the data has been gone. What I'm now left with is a .apk file which I kept as a back up. I somehow managed to get my code back from that .apk file but not sure of how to import the whole project in Eclipse. The source along with other folders like drawables, values, manifest etc are saved in one folder. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you want to decomplie app ? yes

Answer (score 0):

I have two methods :

1. Download APKTool ([url](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)) and decompile your apk package. [Here](http://www.miui-au.com/add-ons/apktool/) you have a tutorial.
   After this you should can import your code into Ecplise.
2. Go to a specialist and try to restore your harddisk.

I hope I helped

Answer (score -1):

ok, first of all, if you tried to decompile an app, I suposed you have used apk-tool or smali/backsmali tools for the code.

1. AFAIK you can't get your java code back. after decompile, you get smali code, which is some dalvik assembly language. I don't think you want to write apps in that.
2. If you were the developer of the app, you would've make a backup of your code, not APK. So, are you sure you're not lying to us?

Comment: Not everyone makes backups of their code, especially beginners. Don't assume that just because he wants to decompile something that he has malicious intent.

Comment: why do rewrite my answer ?

Comment: I did not. By the time I was writing, you answered. I haven't read your answer. You clearly never lost a project that you worked a few months on it, that's why you are not making back-up.

Comment: I followed a tutorial and first converted my classes.dex file to jar file and then used java decompiler to decompile that jar file. Now I have BackUp.jar.src folder that contains all my code. I dont know how to import that on eclipse so that I may continue on with the project :(